# Truncate three different Excel sheets using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have exported data from single SQL table into three different sheets in single Excel file using SSIS package. When I run this SSIS package again data getting appended in Excel sheets. How to truncate the value in 3 sheets?

Comment: You just need an empty excel file to start with each time your process runs?

Comment: I'm trying to export data region wise in different sheets in single excel file..everyday I need to run the package..source sql server...when I run next time previous data shd b truncated and new values has to b inserted...sheets name lik Asia ,Africa ,America

Answer (score 0):

You could store a blank copy of your excel file (with appropriate headers) as a template.
Then before each run of the SSIS package you could archive the 
existing copy (that has data from the previous run) to an archive location and then make a copy of the 
template excel file and put it in the working folder for the 
SSIS package to use.

This can all be done by using SSIS File System Task and creating  template, archive, and work folders in your file location.